# overlay one part of image onto another image

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, scikit-image

There are two corresponding images, the second one reflects the mask area of the first one.

[image: the first image]
[image]

How to over lay the red area in the second image onto the first image?

Comment: Will the result be a grey image with a red splodge? Is it always red and blue?

Comment: Should the red splodge be overlaid semi-transparent on the grey image? Or solid red?

Comment: You don't need any Python by the way, you can just do it in Terminal with **ImageMagick** like this `magick image.jpg \( overlay.jpg -fuzz 30% -transparent blue \) -composite result.png`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with **OpenCV** like this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import numpy as np
import cv2

# Load base image and overlay
base = cv2.imread("image.jpg",   cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
over = cv2.imread("overlay.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

# Anywhere the red channel of overlay image exceeds 127, make base image red
# Remember OpenCV uses BGR ordering, not RGB
base[over[...,2]>127] = [0,0,255]

# Save result
cv2.imwrite('result.jpg',base)
```

[image]

---

If you wanted to blend a small percentage of red (say 20%) while retaining the structure of the underlying image, you could do this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import numpy as np
import cv2

# Load base image and overlay
base = cv2.imread("image.jpg",   cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
over = cv2.imread("overlay.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

# Blend 80% of the base layer with 20% red
blended = cv2.addWeighted(base,0.8,(np.zeros_like(base)+[0,0,255]).astype(np.uint8),0.2,0)

# Anywhere the red channel of overlay image exceeds 127, use blended image, elsewhere use base
result = np.where((over[...,2]>127)[...,None], blended, base)

# Save result
cv2.imwrite('result.jpg',result)
```

[image]

---

By the way, you don't actually need any Python, you can just do it in Terminal with **ImageMagick** like this:

```
magick image.jpg \( overlay.jpg -fuzz 30% -transparent blue \) -composite result.png
```

[image]

---

**Keywords**: Python, image processing, overlay, mask.